# C# Cleaner way to check for checkbox states?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox

I have the following code which takes List of boolean as a parameter then sets the checked state of each checkList by individually verifying the list.

Is there a much more efficient way of writing the following code? For instance, by using a loop?

```
public PointCtrlRowSelectionForm(List<Boolean> checkList, PointCtrlForm form, string title)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.form = form;
                this.Text = title;
                if (checkList[0] == true)      
                {
                    checkBox1.Checked = true;
                    checkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
                }
                if (checkList[1] == true)
                {
                    checkBox2.Checked = true;
                    checkBox3.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
                }
                if (checkList[2] == true)
                {
                    checkBox3.Checked = true;
                    checkBox3.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
                }
                if (checkList[3] == true)
                {
                    checkBox4.Checked = true;
                    checkBox4.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
                }
                if (checkList[4] == true)
                {
                    checkBox5.Checked = true;
                    checkBox5.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
                }
                if (checkList[5] == true)
                {
                    checkBox6.Checked = true;
                    checkBox6.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
                }           
            }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make an array of those checkboxes.  You can make all that a for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < checklist.Length; i++)
{
    if (checklist[i].Checked == true)
    {
        arrayOfCheckboxes[i].Checked = true;
        arrayOfCheckboxes[i].CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your List into a Dictionary and do a simple enumeration though them like so:

```
public PointCtrlRowSelectionForm(Dictionary<CheckBox, Boolean> checkList, PointCtrlForm form, string title)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.form = form;
            this.Text = title;

            foreach<KeyValuePair<CheckBox, Boolean> kvp in checklist)
            {
                if (kvp.Value == true)      
                {
                    kvp.Key.Checked = true;
                    kvp.Key.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This solution might cause some issues when it comes to multithreading and serialization + the checkboxes might not be available when the checklist values are fetched + At some point, you will still have to feed data into your dictionary and I can't see how you would do that without passing each checkbox independently. I might be wrong though

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no *Control Grouping* feature supported by the IDE form designer.
Depending on how you design your form, there are 4 methods I can think of:

1. Change the auto-generated code and add the `CheckBox` instances to an array (not recommended).
2. Keep the auto-generated code intact but create a second array referring to each `CheckBox`.

   ```
   CheckBox[] checkboxes = new CheckBox[]{checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3};
   ```
3. Put all your `Checkbox` instances into a group control. You can then cycle through the `Controls` property of this group. Use the `Tag` property of each `CheckBox` to select an index (an alternative to this could be to use the `TabIndex` instead or to rely on the order in which the `CheckBox` instances are found).

   ```
   bool[] check_list = new bool[] { true, true, false };
   private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     foreach (Control c in groupBox1.Controls)
     {
       if (c is CheckBox)
       {
         CheckBox current = c as CheckBox;
         current.Checked = check_list[int.Parse(current.Tag.ToString())];
       }
     }
   }
   ```
4. Do the same as the previous solution but on your main form.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your checkboxes are actually named in a repeatable pattern like that, then you could do some reflection like:

```
Type myType = this.GetType();
for(int i=0; i < checkList.Length; i++)
{
    string fieldName = String.Format("checkBox{0}", i);
    FieldInfo info = myType.GetField(fieldName);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)info.GetValue(this);
    if(checkList[i] == true)
    {
        cb.Checked = true;
        cb.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
    }
}
```

This is a little more verbose, but a lot more flexible, you can add more or less checkboxes without modifying this code (assuming you stick to a naming pattern).